# How to edit value of tag but do not change style of tag XML file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsxmlparser

I used the below code to save xml file but my xml file is changed style. example: before edit, many empty tags has  but after edit value of tags, all style of xml file has changed, many empty tags are changed to . I don't want to change style of XML file. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

```
// get the xml document
    NSXMLDocument* xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:dataText options:(NSXMLNodePreserveWhitespace | NSXMLNodePreserveCDATA)  error:&err];

    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"There was an error reading the xml document.");
        return ;
    }
    NSXMLElement* root  = [xmlDoc rootElement];

    // look for  tags
    NSArray* a = [root nodesForXPath:@"//a" error:nil];

    // change a specific theme tag value
    for(NSXMLElement* Element in a) {
        [Element setStringValue: textfield_txt.stringValue];
    }

    // write xmlDoc to file
    NSData* xmlData = [xmlDoc XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePreserveAll];
    NSLog(@"xmlData %@",xmlData);
    NSMutableData * datawrite = [xmlData mutableCopy ] ;

    [datawrite writeToURL:furl options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&err];
```

And this is xml file:

Before :

```
<FileSize></FileSize>
<MAC></MAC>
```

After edit, it changed to :

```
<FileSize/>
<MAC/>
```

Comment: Can you show a before and after XML example ?

Comment: @uchuugaka: i updated my question. Pls check it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using NSXMLDocument you should use the NSXMLNode methods. 
setName: is probably what you're looking for. 
NSXMLNode is the important class in this.